# Proving statments about sets (Homework help)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I had some homework questions I couldn't really understand I talked it over with some friends and I feel that I am missing the concept on how to do these questions. I have finished most of the problems without too much difficulty but these 3 questions stumped me. Any help is much appreciated.

1. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two sets with $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = A \times A$. Prove that $A \subseteq B$.
2. Suppose that $f, g : R \rightarrow R$ are two functions and $(f+g),(f-g)$ are bounded. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are bounded functions
3. Define $f : R \rightarrow R$ via $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)}$ Prove that the image of $f$ is $[0, 1)$.

Also this is a proofs class so for #3 I can use calculus methods like limits, derivatives or I.V.T

Still need some help please

Comment: Just a terminology note. You can't "prove a set," as in your title. You can prove statements about sets, of course, which is what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

(1) If $x\in A$, then $(x,x)\in A\times B$ or  $(x,x)\in B\times A$.

(2) Express $f$ and $g$ in terms of $f+g$ and $f-g$.

(3) $f(0)=0$.

If $x\ne0$, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2}>0$ and $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}$.

---

(1) If $x\in A$, then $(x,x)\in A\times B$ or  $(x,x)\in B\times A$. Both $(x,x)\in A\times B$ and $(x,x)\in B\times A$ imply that $x\in B$.

Therefore, $A\subseteq B$

(2) $f+g$ and $f-g$ are bounded, there exist $M_1>0$ and $M_2>0$ such that $|(f+g)(x)|\le M_1$ and $|(f-g)(x)|\le M_2$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

$$|f(x)|=|\frac{1}{2}(f+g)(x)+\frac{1}{2}(f-g)(x)|\le \frac{1}{2}|(f+g)(x)|+\frac{1}{2}|(f-g)(x)|\le M_1+M_2$$

$$|g(x)|=|\frac{1}{2}(f+g)(x)-\frac{1}{2}(f-g)(x)|\le \frac{1}{2}|(f+g)(x)|+\frac{1}{2}|(f-g)(x)|\le M_1+M_2$$

Both $f$ and $g$ are bounded.

(3) If $x=0$, $f(x)=0\in[0,1)$.
if $x\ne0$. $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}<1$ and hence $f(x)\in[0,1)$.

Conversely, suppose that $y\in[0,1)$. If $y=0$, then $f(0)=y$. If $y>0$, let $x=\sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}}$.  Then $x^2=\frac{y}{1-y}$ and $x^2+1=\frac{y}{1-y}+1=\frac{1}{1-y}$. So $f(x)=y$.

$[0,1)$ is the image.